# How to set "no-style" as default in FireFox

Tags: css, firefox

in FireFox 'options' => 'content', I can turn off JavaScript and image loading by default. By I don't see any places to turn off page style by default.

What I want to do is like automatically selecting 'view' => 'Page Style' => 'No Style' when every new page is loaded.

Thanks.

Comment: Not programming related - probably belongs on superuser.com

Comment: several days ago, i asked basically the same thing here: http://superuser.com/questions/450980/render-pages-with-no-style-by-default-in-firefox  - sorry, did not see this one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This setting persists for me.

```
View -> Page Style -> No Style
```

I navigated to a new page, a different site, and even closed and re-opened the browser and it still remained on "No Style".

Edit: Ah I see - when I open a new tab however, it goes back to basic page style.  It appears this is per-tab.

What you can do instead of "No Style" is use [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108/) and write a plugin that resets styles.